# Is it safe to reuse newer LP siding?

Tags: siding, composite, reuse

Is it safe (from water intrusion perspective mostly) to reuse newish LP siding?

My project is to basically re-sheath, wrap and reside 3 walls. On the largest wall I pulled off this siding which was made either 5 mar 2023 or 3 may 2023. Either way it's pretty new. It looks like it's in fantastic condition.

I read this website https://coloradosidingrepair.com/blog/damaged-composite-wood-siding-needs-replacement/ which says to just replace the whole wall for"integrity", but that's for a damaged side. This siding isn't damaged.

Thanks[showing product label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIBXM.jpg)
[image: manufacture date]

Comment: If in good condition, use it.  You probably can build a whole house with wood people throw out.  The age usually does not matter, only the condition of the wood/siding/sheets.  So made this year or 30 years ago it is usually still good to use.

Comment: "reside"? Oh, that's "re-side" not "reside (there)"... I'm stumped, though, on your project to "research" a wall... Care to [edit] a better explanation into your question?

Comment: @crip659, LP lost a class-action lawsuit over a siding product for big, big bucks back in the 90s. I think that may be why the OP mentioned LP and the panel age. Older realtors talk about LP siding like it's made of asbestos.

Comment: @FreeMan "re-sheath" not research.

Comment: @popham   Interesting.  OP's picture looks like standard OSB sheeting.  Unknown if the siding is on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2023 stamped on it, so yes, reuse it if its free of damage. If it was dated between 1985 to 1995, then I would do some additional research to verify that the particular product wasn't recalled by LP (they lost upwards of 1B USD in a class action lawsuit for a product manufactured between 1985 and 1995).

Looking at the website that you referenced, I can only speculate about what they intended by

> Repair and Replacement Alternatives
>
> Depending on the type, age and level of damage, a partial siding replacement may work to fix the issue. If the current siding is a better-quality, composite wood material like LP SmartSide, a partial replacement is an option. Though, *this still usually requires the entire wall to be replaced in order to ensure the integrity of the replacement siding installation.*

I suspect that they don't warranty partial replacement work like they do a full replacement.